# moving <tr> based on whether checkbox contained within the <tr> is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a 'papers' table which contains 6 rows and 2 columns. In the first column is a checkbox and in the second row is the title of the paper.
Once a user has checked 2 checkboxes i would like the rows which have unchecked checkboxes to move below the rows which have checked checkboxes.

I can get the checkboxes themselves to move but not the entire row! Any help you are willing to give is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance :)

```js
        function core2() {
            var i = 0;

            $('.ATT').each(function () { if ($(this).is(':checked')) { i += 1 } });
            });

            if (i < 2 ) {
                $(".ATT:not(:checked)").insertBefore("#core2");

            };


            if (i == 2) {
                $(".ATT:not(:checked)").insertAfter("#core2");
               

            };

        }
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr class="core1" ><td><input type = "checkbox" name="examlist"  value="ATTPTAX" id="ATTPTAX1"  class="ATT" onclick ="if(core2()){this.checked=false};" /></td> <td 
          PAPER 1
          </td> <td>
          </label></td></tr>
    <tr class="core1" ><td><input type = "checkbox" name="examlist"  value="ATTPTAX" id="ATTPTAX2"  class="ATT" onclick ="if(core2()){this.checked=false};" /></td> <td 
          PAPER 2
          </td> <td>
          </label></td></tr>
    <tr class="core1" ><td><input type = "checkbox" name="examlist"  value="ATTPTAX" id="ATTPTAX3"  class="ATT" onclick ="if(core2()){this.checked=false};" /></td> <td 
          PAPER 3
          </td> <td>
          </label></td></tr>
    <tr class="core1" ><td><input type = "checkbox" name="examlist"  value="ATTPTAX" id="ATTPTAX4"  class="ATT" onclick ="if(core2()){this.checked=false};" /></td> <td 
          PAPER 4
          </td> <td>
          </label></td></tr>
    <tr class="core1" ><td><input type = "checkbox" name="examlist"  value="ATTPTAX" id="ATTPTAX5"  class="ATT" onclick ="if(core2()){this.checked=false};" /></td> <td 
          PAPER 5
          </td> <td>
          </label></td></tr>
    <tr class="core1" ><td><input type = "checkbox" name="examlist"  value="ATTPTAX" id="ATTPTAX6"  class="ATT" onclick ="if(core2()){this.checked=false};" /></td> <td 
          PAPER 6
          </td> <td>
          </label></td></tr>
<tr id="core2"><td>Core 2</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your HTML as

```
<table>
      <tr class="core1" >
        <td>
        <input type = "checkbox" name="examlist[]"  value="ATTPTAX" id="ATTPTAX1"  class="ATT"/>
        </td> 
        <td>
            PAPER 1
        </td> 
      </tr>
      <tr class="core" >
        <td>
        <input type = "checkbox" name="examlist[]"  value="ATTPTAX" id="ATTPTAX1"  class="ATT" />
        </td> 
        <td>
            PAPER 2
        </td> 
      </tr>
      <tr class="core" >
        <td>
        <input type = "checkbox" name="examlist[]"  value="ATTPTAX" id="ATTPTAX1"  class="ATT" />
        </td> 
        <td>
            PAPER 3
        </td> 
      </tr>
      <tr class="core" >
        <td>
        <input type = "checkbox" name="examlist[]"  value="ATTPTAX" id="ATTPTAX1"  class="ATT" />
        </td> 
        <td>
            PAPER 4
        </td> 
      </tr>
      <tr class="core" >
        <td>
        <input type = "checkbox" name="examlist[]"  value="ATTPTAX" id="ATTPTAX1"  class="ATT" />
        </td> 
        <td>
            PAPER 5
        </td> 
      </tr>
      <tr class="core" >
        <td>
        <input type = "checkbox" name="examlist[]"  value="ATTPTAX" id="ATTPTAX1"  class="ATT"/>
        </td> 
        <td>
            PAPER 6
        </td> 
      </tr>
</table>
```

Your Jquery Code will be:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
  var index = 0;
  $('input:checked').each(function(){
    $('table').prepend($(this).parents('tr'));
    index++;
  })
});
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ys219mbt/1/

Answer (score 0):

To insert a table row (`tr`) before another one, you need to ad an univocal id to each of your rows, and then use this code:

```
function InsertRowBefore(rowId) {
  var target = document.getElementById(rowId);
  var element = document.createElement('tr');
  target.parentNode.insertBefore(element, target);
  return element;
}
```

Comment: It's not a requirement to give each row a unique id, as long as you can get the DOM element somehow.